# Pictures are not loading at view controller start up Swift

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, swift5, alamofireimage

I am using import AlamofireImage/Alamofire to load up pictures I am downloading from Firebase Storage on my tableview cells. However, when I run the app, I cannot see the pictures unless I navigate to a different page and then come back to the tableview page. Can anyone help?

[At application start up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SFMm.png)

[After I navigate to a different view controller and coming back to the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFqxO.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = topNewsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topNewsCell", for: indexPath) as! TopNewsCell
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    cell.favoriteDelegate = self
    cell.share.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.collect.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let article = articles[indexPath.row]
    cell.topNewsText.text = article.title
    let imageRef = storageRef.child("images/" + article.imageURL)
    cell.imageView?.isHidden = true
    if article.imageURL != ""{
                imageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                  if let error = error {
                  } else {
                    cell.imageView?.isHidden = false
                    AF.request(url!).responseData { (response) in
                        if response.error == nil {
                            if let data = response.data {
                                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                                cell.imageView?.isHidden = false
                                cell.imageView?.image = self.resizeImage(image: image!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 350.0, height: 300.0))

                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
    }
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: Everytime image is being fetched from the db, so it's taking time for image to download and display. Use caching to avoid redownloading images and also you can show download progress loader over image view to specify some kind of downloading

Comment: Even if I stay in the page for 10 minutes, no image will be shown. But if I switch to a different page and come back to the firs page, it shows immediately. I don't think the issue is the long time to download the image. The issue is updating the imageView.

Comment: Try setting the image on main thread i.e. `DispatchQueue.main.async{ }`. If that doesn't work try reloading the tableView i.e `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Performing this download in cellForRowAt indexpath will cause it redownload images when you scroll the page up and down. So try some solution like SDWebImage (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYbD7Ab3FH4)